Problems with custom model user in Django 5.0
I'm pretty new in this world of django apps so I'm still learning how the things works.
I'm trying to do a CRUD for my work, so we can register some things like clients info, ours tasks, assistance... etc. In an entuthiastic and young learning spirit I decided to make a custom user model in order to be able to add a profile picture of the users of this app. I was part succeded while I was able to add users and edit its info in the app but some problems came to me later:

I can create users from Django admin pannell but then this users can't logging neither the app nor the admin pannell even when I created this with the superuser and staff marks on.

I can make a relation between my users and groups of the model auth.Group.


To solve 1) or at least to live with it, I found I can create users with the terminal and the command 'createsuperuser' and remove permissions later altought I suspect this 'removing permission' don't work at all. But for the purpose of this project I tought it wold be fine anyway at least for now.
I include this lines in my custom_user_model_apps' views.py of my django project:
...
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
...

...
class User(AbstractUser):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=profile_picture_path, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    dark_mode = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    telephone = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
...


And in my project settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
my_app's_name.apps.AsistenciasConfig'
...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app's_name.User'


I'm using this funciton to make the login part:
def Log_in_function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Wrong username or password.')

    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'core/login.html', {'form': form})


And I'm obtaining the 'Wrong username ...' message in my localhost and the admin panel.I'm gessing the 'authenticate' function is pointing some way to the users of 'auth.user' and not to my 'my_name_app.user' so when it tries to authenticate a giving username and pasword it fails because there is nothing there...

Advancing with my project I thought it would be good filter some actions deppending on who is logged in, so I try to use django groups and this way I discovered that seems to be that the model Group that Django itself creates is completely separated of my custom user model 'User'. This way, even when I can create groups in django admin panel I can't assigning this to my users and all my user are part of all the groups I created (maybe because they where created with the command 'superuser') even when groups arrived much later than users.

I tried to add a 'group' field with both, 'ForeingKey' and 'ManyToMany' relations to 'auth.Group' from my user model but this just add a field in my user creation/editing form parrallel to the Group of auth.Group and still can't assigning a particular group to a given user. So, to this point I'm pretty lost of what can I do to solve this issue.
Any idea?
Edit: Finally I was able to do all I wanted thanks to @CoffeeBasedLifeform and his suggestion of make an extension of the django User model and removing all the 'links' to the custom model from the rest of my project and 'linking' the original (but extended) model of User instead.
P/S: I'm also new in this community so Idk how to close this thread as solved or indicate that in this case the CoffeBasedLifeform's answer was enough.

About 1: did you register the new User model with the admin? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project I have a hunch that UserAdmin still uses the default User model.

About 2: the docs recommend using the LoginView view class rather than using authenticate directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users You just need to declare a template_name and a next_page (the URL to redirect to after a successful login) and it should just work.

Yes, I forgot to indicate that the custom model of user is registered in the app's admin.py file. I could try to use the LoginView but I don't remember why I left it in first place.
My problem 2 is with groups, I wish that people from certain groups are able (or not) to do some things like add, edit or delete registers but I can't make Groups have a relation with my users. Maybe I should edit my question to make it clear?
Thanks for your answer.

Did you create your custom user model after you have created the database tables? That could be an issue: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

I guess it is the main problem, sincerarly I worked so much in this project now that I don't know if I did de modifications of my User model after some migrations... I assume that if I delete/remove the data base and all the migrations and then add the Group model to the same app as User it could work?
Even in that case I don't think it would 'fix' the users being unable to log if I created its in the admin pannell (?).

You could try extending the default User model with a OneToOne relation first: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model (to test, you can just remove references to your custom User from settings and any views, admin, etc.)

I think your problem comes from this line : user = authenticate(username=username, password=password). You must pass the request argument at first and than pass username and password. give it try. `user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

Hi @Sooshiance! Before make mi question I was reading some similar threads and found this indication of pass the request to authenticate and I maked several tries withouth success. So Idk, at this point I bet I screw up whit the order of creation of my custom model and my first migrations... but at least, extending the native Django user model I was able to work with groups and make all the users able to login.
